# How to use GROUP BY and COUNT in SQL in this scenario

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, relationship

I am working on a voting system, there is a survey form, I record the data like this

```
survey
--------------
id
q1
q2
q3
```

where q1 means question 1, the possible value is 1, 2 , 3, (means the user select first , second ..choice) while the q2 means question 2 , the possible value is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ..etc

And I would like to have a query in this case, for each question, count the total number of each choice, so , the query result should be like this  e.g.

```
q1 , first choice , 10
q1 , second, 50
q1 , third , 20...and so on
```

I think of this way but are there any other elegant approach ? Thanks

```
(SELECT COUNT(1) as q1_third FROM survey WHERE q1 = 3)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with case statements within a COUNT or SUM() like you see below.

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN q1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as q1_first,
    SUM(CASE WHEN q1 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as q1_second,
    SUM(CASE WHEN q1 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as q1_third
FROM survey
```

Comment: @user3538235 I'd recommend to use SUM instead of COUNT

Comment: Right because a 0 still counts as something... thanks :)

Comment: COUNT(CASE WHEN q1 = 1 THEN q1 ELSE null END) if you want to use COUNT

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be more elegant:

```
select 'q1', q1, count(*) as n from survey group by q1
union all
select 'q2', q2, count(*) as n from survey group by q2
union all
select 'q3', q3, count(*) as n from survey group by q3
order by 1, 2
```